# Dockerfile : Running client/server python scripts

Tags: python, docker

In my dockerfile I have the following lines :

```
CMD [ "python", "./server.py" ]
CMD [ "python", "./client.py" ]
```

But the connection between the two is refused, am I doing this wrong ?

Comment: Only the latest `CMD` will be run. Maybe you could try putting them in different Docker images and running both at the same time on a network? Can you share your whole Dockerfile?

Comment: 1) This largely depends on your Python files 2) Only the client `CMD` is ran, so, yes, a connection should be refused.

Comment: Ideally, you have the container just running the server. Your host machine should be the client. Unclear why you have a container being both.

Comment: My Dockerfile just installs the dependencies and copies the two files to the container.
Is there a way to run the two at the same time without putting them in differents images ?

Comment: For what reason are you against separate images? What's the use case here?

Comment: just write a launcher.py/launcher.sh and run that that kicks off and divorces the server/client.

Comment: You can create a single image with both files in it but run 2 containers each running each script. You can use docker-compose to run them easily.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation : There can only be one CMD instruction in a Dockerfile. If you list more than one CMD then only the last CMD will take effect.

You can build two dockets. One for the client and one for the server and communicate between the two.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done to allow me to daemonize(start/disown) multiple processes:

Because of some weirdness with nohup (it cannot apparently directly disown python programs over ssh), this needs to be in a separate script to work properly:
`startlocal.sh`:

```
python server.py > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

What you run:

`start.sh`:

```
nohup ./startlocal.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
nohup ./startlocal2.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
...
```

I don't think the `/dev/null...` is required for both, but this works (even over SSH). with docker, you want the command to take forever, so at the end you can just:

```
sleep infinity
```

and it won't exit.